# Comparison Function Returns True or False

Tags: functional-programming, comparison

In my python CS class at school, we were given a true or false question as follows.

> A comparison function returns either True or False.

When originally answering I thought about two things.  First, a function as follows (what I thought was a comparison function) returns true or false.

```
def comparison(valOne,valTwo):
    return valOne<valTwo
```

Now, I know this isn't a comparison function, but a function with an operator.  In addition, I thought of another type of function when answering.

```
def someoneHasOne(scoreOne,scoreTwo):
    return scoreOne==15 or scoreTwo==15
```

> From what I know, this **is** a comparison function.
>
> So, thinking of those two things, I marked this as `True`.

However, the correct answer, according to the teacher, was `False`.  After the answer was marked wrong, I started to do some research.  I found [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) about the operator module that has comparison functions that return `True` or `False`

> My main question is, am I right (the answer is `True`)? Or is my CS teacher right (the answer is `False`)?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "comparison function". Sometimes you want a three-way comparison so that you can handle "less than", "equal to", and "greater than" separately, rather than e.g. just "less than" and "not less than". In some languages (PHP among them), you use the spaceship operator `<=>` for this. In Python 2, the `cmp` function does the same thing. For a three-way comparison, True/False clearly doesn't suffice. More common is to return -1, 0, 1. In languages with good sum types like Haskell, you're more likely to see something like `LT | EQ | GT`.

Comment: For other languages to see how this works - `strcmp` for C, `<=>` and `cmp` for perl, `compareTo` from `Comparable` or the `Comparator` in Java, `IComparable.CompareTo` and `Comparison<T>` in C#, the `Ordered` trait with `compare` in scala, `(compare x y)` in Scala...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a python class, then yes, your CS teacher is correct.  A number of python functions take a "comparison function" as an argument.  For instance, see the [sorted](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) documentation:

> cmp specifies a custom comparison function of two arguments (iterable elements) which should return a negative, zero or positive number depending on whether the first argument is considered smaller than, equal to, or larger than the second argument: cmp=lambda x,y: cmp(x.lower(), y.lower()). The default value is None.

How comparison functions work varies by language, though most follow a similar fashion.  But since this is specifically a question about python, the answer is unambiguously "false" in that comparison functions do not always return just `True` or `False`.

Comment: alternatively this is called something different in other languages e.g. java 8 would call this a BiPredicate